# SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url IS NULL syntax error exception

Tags: java, jdbc

```
Connection conn = null;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/madb?&user=root&password=root");
PreparedStatement ps =
       conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url IS NULL");
```

I'm getting

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null' at line 1

How can I do this using jdbc and mysql?

Comment: Obvious things to double-check: (1) Wrong database? (2) The query you're showing isn't the query that's failing?

Comment: Why are you using a `PreparedStatement`, there are no variables for replacement in what you are listing?

Comment: is your actual table really named mytable? what's the real name? maybe you are using a keyword. If that's the case, put double quotes around it. `"SELECT * FROM \"keywordconflictingtablename\" WHERE url IS NULL"`

Comment: @JarrodRoberson Well it fails on this line, theres no necessity to post what comes after. But if you want to see it I can put it here...

Comment: I only get this exact error message for the query `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE url IS NULL null` (two null). If the table name or column name are wrong, I get a different message. But it's clearly better to copy the *whole* statement. You didn't, otherwise NULL would be uppercase in the error message.

Comment: I'm actually using java.sql.PreparedStatement not the jdbc one. Could this be the problem ?

Comment: @ThomasMueller: the case don't matter, the stack trace is lower case...

Comment: @myro `java.sql.PreparedStatement` *is* the JDBC one!

Comment: @myro: the case *does* matter.

Comment: @adarshr ok but why cannot I do this: om.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(etc... ?

Comment: You should use the Java versions which are interfaces. The actual implementation you get is driver-dependent.

Comment: `PreparedStatement` isn't the appropriate thing to use here, not unless you are replacing parameters `?`, which you aren't. Just use a normal `Statement` and `.executeQuery()` that.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. The code wasn't a problem, but it was something with compiler or what. I had to delete a dependence on another project, move that class into my project, rebuild an it works.

Comment: could you please vote to close the question, so that it doesn't bother anyone

Answer (score 2):

I see no reason why this query would fail, especially given that it works in Query Browser.

Here are some possibilities that might explain the behaviour:

1. The code is connecting to the wrong database.
2. You're looking at the wrong query (i.e. it's some other query that's actually failing). Notice how the error message has the word `null` in lowercase, whereas the query has it in uppercase. This looks fishy.
3. The Java code you're showing isn't the code you're running (e.g. due to a deployment failure of some sort).

Comment: It could also be wrong code! Code that failed to get deployed for some reason.

Comment: @adarshr: Good point. Answer updated. Thanks!

Comment: @aix it was something similar...